# CakeFTP "Failed to connect" on remote server

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakeFTP on a project, it's working great on my local computer (connection to a remote FTP server, browse file, download...), but I get a "Failed to connect" error when testing on a remote server (client server). This plugin uses phpSecLib.

I don't manage this server, but I suspect a configuration problem on this server. What could be happening ? Any lead would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use passive mode? Or to check the connection with regular ftp client?

Comment: I didn't try the passive mode, i'll do that. I tried to open a ftp connection from my client's server in command line, but it seems that the simple ftp client is not installed ("unknown command"...) and I can't install it